# Access Chrome bookmarks online w/o Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

Is there any way to access them online WITHOUT Chrome? I mean open some page in other browser and view them?

Or way to sync them to some service (like Raindrop or Palapy) not via file but through API?

I found only [this page](https://chrome.google.com/sync) where you view stats but not bookmarks themselves.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of today I could not Access my "Google Chrome Bookmarks" online without Chrome but there is a way around it.

The basic idea is you download a .html file containing your chrome bookmarks from google's database. Here is a step by step instructions that is valid now but google might modify the process and in that case look for a way to export your data from google. During export select only your Chrome Bookmarks.

1. Goto https://takeout.google.com/
2. Select only "Chrome"
3. Click "All Chrome data included" and select only "Bookmarks"
4. Click "Next step"
5. Select Delivery method e.g. "Send download link via email", "Export once", .zip, 1GB
6. Click "Create export"
7. Now in this stage you should be able to download directly or use the link you received by email to download a .zip file, which contains a file named "Bookmarks.html".

You can now use "bookmarks.html" file to import bookmarks in other browser, which you currently have access, to import chrome bookmarks.

Keep in mind https://www.google.com/bookmarks/ is different from the bookmarks you have in your chrome browser.

Comment: Please, could you explain how is this different than the resulting bookmarks.html file you'd get by simply exporting them from Bookmarks manager (Ctrl-Shift-O)?

Comment: @DomDelimar I believe there is a misunderstanding on your part regarding the actual question. The key phrase here is "Without access to a chrome browser" e.g sometimes you are in a remote PC without admin rights to install chrome and want to access your chrome bookmarks which you don't have a back up copy of, since most people don't carry their chrome bookmarks with them/keep a backup copy in email/drive. Situation like this needs this complex solution.

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks for clarification.

But to be sure, there's no difference in the resulting HTML file, it's just that that with takeout.google.com, one can download it even if on a public restricted system, with no Chrome available. That's actually great! (even if what I was looking for is something like google.com/bookmarks - eh...)

Comment: Apparently, this method doesn't work for me.  Even though I get an archive from Google Takeout and there is a file called Bookmarks.html inside, the file is just saying one sentence: "Your data is encrypted and cannot be exported.".  Ugh.

Comment: Just tried myself. For me it works. Not sure why yours is encrypted, I also see few other people mentioning similar encryption issue but no solution so far. Just throwing random suggestion : check if the device/drive is encrypted. Also update us if you can solve the issue.

Comment: No encryption problem in my case, BUT it only saves folders names and hierarchy (even date of creation and last modification) but no links. Well, indeed just two out of my hundreds.

Answer (score -3):

You could export them in Chrome in the Bookmark Manager (right click on the Bookmarks bar) -> Export bookmarks (top right three dots).

This gives you an html file, which you can view in any browser.

Comment: I specified "without Chrome" in title

Comment: @Suncatcher If you created them in Chrome, then you can also export them.

Comment: Sometimes I am on a guest PC or somewhere on public wifi when I want to quickly check some of the bookmarks but have no my Chrome in-place, this is exactly the case why I created the question